# Access a JSON child object for that specific JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I am playing around with promises and API calls, this time with https://www.warcraftlogs.com/v1/docs. The goal of this example is when you click the `zones` button all the zones will show up, and allow you to click on them (that part is done). The next part is to show detailed information about a particular zone when `clicked`, in this case the `encounters` array in the zone object.

Here is the pen in question: http://codepen.io/kresimircoko/pen/ZLJjVM?editors=0011.

The question is how to access the `encounters` array for the `zone` that the user has clicked on?

And the code:

```
    const API_KEY = '?api_key=625023d7336dd01a98098c0b68daab7e';
    const root = 'https://www.warcraftlogs.com:443/v1/';
    const zonesBtn = document.querySelector('#zones');
    const responseList = document.querySelector('#response');
    console.clear();

    const requestJSON = objType => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onload = function() {
                try {
                    resolve(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
                }
                catch (e) {
                    reject(e);
                }
            };
            xhr.onerror = reject;
            xhr.open('GET', root + objType + API_KEY);
            xhr.send();
        });
    };
    function displayBosses(zoneID) {
        requestJSON('zones')
            .then(data => {
                return data.find(zone => {
                    return zone.id === zoneID;
                });
            })
    }

    function displayZones() {
        let output = '';
        requestJSON('zones')
            .then(zones => {
                return zones.map(zone => {
                    output += `<li data-zoneid="${zone.id}"> ${zone.name} </li>`;
                    response.innerHTML = output;
                }).join('');
            })
            .then( responseList.style.display = 'flex' );
    }

    zonesBtn.addEventListener('click', displayZones);
    responseList.addEventListener('click', evt => {
        const zoneID = evt.target.dataset.zoneid;
        displayBosses(zoneID);
    })
```

Here's a part of the JSON output I'm working with:

```
    [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Challenge Modes",
        "frozen": true,
        "encounters": [
            {
                "id": 11182,
                "name": "Auchindoun"
            },
            {
                "id": 11175,
                "name": "Bloodmaul Slag Mines"
            },
            {
                "id": 11279,
                "name": "The Everbloom"
            },
            {
                "id": 11208,
                "name": "Grimrail Depot"
            },
            {
                "id": 11195,
                "name": "Iron Docks"
            },
            {
                "id": 11176,
                "name": "Shadowmoon Burial Grounds"
            },
            {
                "id": 11209,
                "name": "Skyreach"
            },
            {
                "id": 11358,
                "name": "Upper Blackrock Spire"
            }
        ],
        "brackets": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "6.0"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "6.1"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "6.2"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Throne of Thunder",
        "frozen": true,
        "encounters": [
            {
                "id": 1577,
                "name": "Jin'rokh the Breaker"
            },
            {
                "id": 1575,
                "name": "Horridon"
            },
            {
                "id": 1570,
                "name": "Council of Elders"
            },
            {
                "id": 1565,
                "name": "Tortos"
            },
            {
                "id": 1578,
                "name": "Megaera"
            },
            {
                "id": 1573,
                "name": "Ji-kun"
            },
            {
                "id": 1572,
                "name": "Durumu the Forgotten"
            },
            {
                "id": 1574,
                "name": "Primordius"
            },
            {
                "id": 1576,
                "name": "Dark Animus"
            },
            {
                "id": 1559,
                "name": "Iron Qon"
            },
            {
                "id": 1560,
                "name": "Twin Consorts"
            },
            {
                "id": 1579,
                "name": "Lei Shen"
            },
            {
                "id": 1580,
                "name": "Ra-den"
            }
        ]
    },
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Can you post a sample of the JSON returned from the server please. Without knowing the structure we cannot advise on how to access.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat added a part of the JSON, specifically first 2 objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change function `displayBosses` as shown here (see comments in code):

```
function displayBosses(zoneID) {
    requestJSON('zones')
        .then(data => {
            const encounters = return data.find(zone => {
                return zone.id === parseInt(zoneID, 10); //<-- do parseInt before checking
            }).encounters;  // <-- read property encounters

            console.log(encounters); // <--- variable encounters will have the required data.
        })
}
```

Hope this helps you.

**EDIT:**

To display the new list:

```
function displayBosses(zoneID) {
    requestJSON('zones')
        .then(data => {
          let output = '';
            data.find(zone => zone.id === parseInt(zoneID, 10))
            .encounters
            .forEach(enc => {
                output += `<li data-zoneid="${enc.id}"> ${enc.name} </li>`;
            });

        response.innerHTML = output;

    });
}
```

Comment: Good so far - how would you get displayBosses() to output the list elements in the same manner as displayZones() does for zones?

Comment: That works like a charm, thank you. Do you maybe have some advice on how to generate the HTML for the results? Or should I just do the same thing as I did in the `displayZones` function with `.innerHTML`?

Comment: @VanquishedWombat the OP has asked only **how to access the encounters array for the zone that the user has clicked on**. Nothing has been asked about how to display or where to display.

Comment: @KrešimirČoko It will be almost the same. The only difference is that you will have to remove the existing child `li` elements before putting the new ones.